# ¿Cómo mostrar una consulta SQL server en un TreeView usando C# en visual studio?

Tags: c#

Tengo una consulta en SQL SERVER que me devuelve un resultado como el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría mostrar el resultado de la consulta en un TreeView en C# usando Visual Studio de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! wpf o winforms? pero por lo menos probaste algo? esto es una rutina bastante trivial...

Answer (score 1):

No se como obtienes la consulta, pero debrias obtener una lista de una clase que definas

Entonces define la clase que mepa con la tabla

```
public class ClassTabla
{
    public int campo1 {get;set;}
    public string campo2 {get;set;}
    public string campo3 {get;set;}
}
```

Y luego el metodo que llena la lista y retorna como respuesta

```
public List<ClassTabla> Get(int param1)
{
    List<ClassTabla> listResult = new List<ClassTabla>();

    string connstring = "connection string";  
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {  
        cn.Open();  

        string sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM Tabla WHERE campo4 = @param1";  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@param1", param1);  

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

        while (reader.Read())  
        {  
            ClassTabla item = new ClassTabla()
            {
                campo1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["campo1"]),
                campo2 = Convert.ToString(reader["campo2"]),
                campo3 = Convert.ToString(reader["campo3"]),
            };
            listResult.Add(item);   
        }  

    }

    return listResult;
}
```

Si lo haces asi entonces con la ayudarte con `linq` podras agrupar y obtener la jerarquia que defina cada nodo padre y sus hijos

```
var listClassTabla = Get(..);

var result = from item in listClassTabla
               group item by item.Country into g
              select new {
                 Country = g.Key,
                 States = g
               };

foreach(var root in result){

     TreeNode nodeRoot = new TreeNode(root.Country);

     foreach(var item in root.States){
          TreeNode nodeState = new TreeNode(item.State);
          nodeRoot.Nodes.Add(nodeState);
     }

     treeView1.Nodes.Add(nodeRoot);
}
```

Una vez que agrupar despues iterar la hearquia para armar los nodos es mucho mas simple

Nota: por supuesto debes definir la clase que se adapte a tu tabla para poder usar linq y agrupar, este es solo un ejemplo

Comment: Hola Leandro, gracias por la ayuda, adjunto mas detalles en la siguiente respuesta.

Comment: lo detalles no se adjuntan como respuesta, deberias editar la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

te agradezco mucho. Traté de usar tu ejemplo pero me marco errores en esta parte: var listClassTabla = Get(..);

El query que publiqué con country fue un ejemplo ficticio, el query que estoy usando en verdad es el siguiente:

SELECT (E.cPlantCode) AS cPlantCode  , 
(B.cSkuCode) AS cSkuCode  , 
(A.cMixCode) AS cMixCode  , 
(D.cSkuCode)  AS SkuCode
FROM MIX A
INNER JOIN SKU B ON A.iMixSkuId = B.iSkuId
INNER JOIN MIX_SKU C ON A.iMixId = C.iMixId
INNER JOIN SKU D ON C.iSkuId = D.iSkuId
INNER JOIN PLANT E ON A.iPlantId = E.iPlantId
ORDER BY (E.cPlantCode),
(B.cSkuCode),
(A.cMixCode)

El cual me regresa la siguiente consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito mostrar la consulta en un TreeView de la forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

```
        query = " SELECT (E.cPlantCode + ' - ' + E.cPlantName) AS cPlantCode ";
        query += " , (B.cSkuCode + ' - ' + B.cSkuName) AS cSkuCode ";
        query += " , (A.cMixCode + ' - ' + A.cMixName) AS cMixCode ";
        query += " , (D.cSkuCode)  AS SkuCode ";
        query += " FROM MIX A ";
        query += " INNER JOIN SKU B ON A.iMixSkuId = B.iSkuId ";
        query += " INNER JOIN MIX_SKU C ON A.iMixId = C.iMixId ";
        query += " INNER JOIN SKU D ON C.iSkuId = D.iSkuId ";
        query += " INNER JOIN PLANT E ON A.iPlantId = E.iPlantId ";
        query += " ORDER BY (E.cPlantCode + ' - ' + E.cPlantName), ";
        query += " (B.cSkuCode + ' - ' + B.cSkuName), ";
        query += " (A.cMixCode + ' - ' + A.cMixName) ";

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        //SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //dt.Rows.Add("cPlantCode" typeof(string));
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["cPlantCode"].ToString());
            node.Nodes.Add("cSkuCode", dr["cSkuCode"].ToString());
            node.Nodes["cSkuCode"].Nodes.Add("cMixCode", dr["cMixCode"].ToString());
            node.Nodes["cSkuCode"].Nodes["cMixCode"].Nodes.Add("SkuCode", dr["SkuCode"].ToString());

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Ojalá puedas ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Saludos.